# Kendo format number with white space

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo and i want to format a number with spaces (in my grid columns) like this example:
123456789  to  123 456 789 
But i didnt find this format

is some  one know it?

Comment: How are you configuring your grid, via jquery or HTML Helpers?

Comment: this is my code:

     columns: [
                    {
                        title: "Hello",
                        template: "<span>#: Especes #€</span>",
                        field: "Especes",
                        format: "{0:c}"
                    },

And i want the format with spaces

Comment: How about --> template: "<span>#=jsFunctionToPerformFormatting(Especes)#"</span>" or are you asking is there a format function for number with spaces?

Comment: i am open for the two solutions to insert spaces in my numbers

Comment: how to do it with this function jsFunctionToPerformFormatting(Especes) ?

Comment: according to kendo UI docs you should be able to use something like kendo.toString(number, "## #") ... as @Abdou correctly points out (without even knowing it), the Telerik team have dropped the ball on something fundamental in their framework so we are forced to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format the number with spaces as the thousands separator, you can use the answer from here: [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Assuming no decimals:

```
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}
```

Then your column definition would be

```
{ 
  field: "Especes", 
  title: "Hello",
  template: function(dataItem) {
    return "<span>" + numberWithSpaces(dataItem.Especes) + "</span>"
  }
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AyAjiP)**